# A charge A situated outside hollow conductor experiences a force of another charge B is placed inside the cavity of the conductor

Tags: electrostatics

A charge A situated outside hollow conductor experiences a force of another charge B is placed inside the cavity of the conductor,but B does not experience any force.What may be the reason.Does it violate newtons 3rd law.

This may be a very basic question but i am having a hard time explaining it.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that there are more charges in the system than the two you have mentioned. Just because the inside charge does not experience a net force does not mean it does not experience a force from the outside charge. It is just cancelled out by the forces from all of the other charges in the conductor.

Comment: This is a very instructive problem. Hint: Newton's laws are not violated...

Comment: Draw a diagram which includes any induced charges.